# Sublime build exec command array

Tags: sublimetext2

I am confused as to why Sublime Text 2 build systems tend to put the exec command as an array. Though this is suggested in the docs (and works), just putting the command as a string works just as well, and is (in my opinion) more straightforward.

Comment: The Sublime Text build system calls `subprocess.Popen`, which recommends the usage of an array. Otherwise the behavior is platform-dependent and a string has a significant different behavior on non-Windows systems. Read more in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor).

Comment: If you want to put that in as an answer, I'll close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Sublime Text build system uses `subprocess.Popen`, which recommends the usage of an array. Otherwise the interpretation is platform-dependent.

Cited from the [python 2 subprocess documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor):

> args should be a sequence of program arguments or else a single string. By default, the program to execute is the first item in args if args is a sequence. If args is a string, the interpretation is platform-dependent (...). Unless otherwise stated, it is recommended to pass args as a sequence.

Additional important cite (thanks @Dimpl for pointing that out):

> The shell argument (which defaults to *False*) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is *True*, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.

The shell argument is set *True* if you use the `shell_cmd` and *False* for `cmd`. Hence based on the cites I would suggest to use an array for `cmd` and a string for `shell_cmd`.

Comment: Note (from the above-cited documentation): The shell argument (which defaults to False) specifies whether to use the shell as the program to execute. If shell is True, it is recommended to pass args as a string rather than as a sequence.