# sublime text 3 on ubuntu : how to make work an haskell build system?

Tags: ubuntu, haskell, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I would like to create a building system in order to compile haskell files; note that I don't want to replace the common "CTRL+B" shortcut which runs the current file in a ST window.

so, following [this messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22403119/how-to-create-a-shortcut-for-users-build-system-in-sublime-text), I created this file, located in the directory "/opt/sublime_text":

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin

class MakeHaskellCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
   def run(self, edit):
      self.view.window().run_command('exec', {"working_dir":"${project_path:${folder}}",'cmd': ["ghc","$file"]})
```

then, I modified the user key binding of the sublime-haskell package:

```
[
    {
        "keys": ["f1"],
        "context": [
            { "key": "haskell_source" },
            { "key": "scanned_source" } ],
        "command": "MakeHaskellCommand"
    }
]
```

but after a restart of ST, nothing happens as I hit FN+F1.

can you help me?

EDIT
thanks for your first message!
It works, but now I have an other problem : I would like to delete all files in the directory, except the source file and the binary.
I can launch this plugin:

```
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MakeHaskell2Command(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        variables = self.window.extract_variables()
        args = sublime.expand_variables({
            "working_dir": "${project_path:${file_path}}",
            "cmd": ["rm", "*.hi"],
            "cmd": ["rm", "*.o"]
        }, variables)
        self.window.run_command('exec', args)
```

but it does not remove the files. can you help me again for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a few points:

1. You create plugins in subfolders of Packages, e.g. the User folder
2. The command names in the keymap are snake_case with the ending `Command` stripped of
3. You should use a `WindowCommand` instead of a `TextCommand` for build systems
4. You should press `f1` not `fn+f1`
5. The exec command does not expand the variables

To create your behavior press `Tools >>> New Plugin...`, paste and save:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MakeHaskellCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        variables = self.window.extract_variables()
        args = sublime.expand_variables({
            "working_dir": "${project_path:${file_path}}",
            "cmd": ["ghc", "$file"]
        }, variables)
        self.window.run_command('exec', args)
```

Afterwards open your keymap and insert the keybinding:

```js
{
    "keys": ["f1"],
    "command": "make_haskell",
    "context":
    [
        { "key": "selector", "operator": "equal", "operand": "source.haskell" }
    ]
},
```

Edit:
If you want do cleanup afterwards using the shell `rm` command, then you should use the `shell_cmd` instead of `cmd`. (`exec` assumes the `shell_cmd` to be a string and `cmd` to an array ([why](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35841789/sublime-build-exec-command-array/35889481#35889481)))
I slightly modified the plugin to cleanup afterwards:

```py
import sublime
import sublime_plugin


class MakeHaskellCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
    def run(self):
        variables = self.window.extract_variables()
        args = sublime.expand_variables({
            "working_dir": "$file_path",
            "shell_cmd": "ghc $file && rm $file_base_name.o $file_base_name.hi"
        }, variables)
        self.window.run_command('exec', args)
```